# How to have type reflection in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reflection, yesod

I've written a simple Yesod Rest Server that persists entities in JSON files.
Entities are stored on disk in files named data/type.id.json.
For instance retrieveCustomer "1234" should load data from file data/Customer.1234.json.

I'm using a polymorphic function retrieveEntity that can retrieve instances of any data type that instantiate the FromJSON typeclass. (This part works nicely)

But at the moment I have to fill in the type name hardcoded in type-specific functions like retrieveCustomer.

How do I manage to compute the type name dynamically in the generic retrieveEntity?
I think I'm basically looking for a Haskell type reflection mechanism which I did not come across so far?

```
-- | retrieve a Customer by id
retrieveCustomer :: Text -> IO Customer
retrieveCustomer id = do
    retrieveEntity "Customer" id :: IO Customer

-- | load a persistent entity of type t and identified by id from the backend
retrieveEntity :: (FromJSON a) => String -> Text -> IO a
retrieveEntity t id = do
    let jsonFileName = getPath t id ".json"
    parseFromJsonFile jsonFileName :: FromJSON a => IO a

-- | compute path of data file
getPath :: String -> Text -> String -> String
getPath t id ex = "data/" ++ t ++ "." ++ unpack id ++ ex

-- | read from file fileName and then parse the contents as a FromJSON instance.
parseFromJsonFile :: FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO a
parseFromJsonFile fileName = do
    contentBytes <- B.readFile fileName
    case eitherDecode contentBytes of
        Left msg -> fail msg
        Right x  -> return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the standard trick is to use `Typeable`, specifically `typeOf :: Typeable a => a -> TypeRep`. Unfortunately, we don't have an `a` lying around to call this on until after we've read the file, which we can't do until we have the right filename, which we can't do until we call `typeOf`, which we can't do until after we've read the file...

...or can we?

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Data.Typeable
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

retrieveEntity :: (FromJSON a, Typeable a) => Text -> IO a
retrieveEntity id = mdo
    let jsonFileName = getPath (typeOf result) id ".json"
    result <- parseFromJsonFile jsonFileName
    return result

getPath :: TypeRep -> Text -> String -> String
getPath tr id ex = "data/" ++ show tr ++ "." ++ unpack id ++ ex

parseFromJsonFile :: FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO a
parseFromJsonFile fileName = do
    contentBytes <- B.readFile fileName
    case eitherDecode contentBytes of
        Left msg -> fail msg
        Right x  -> return x
```

Or there are less mind-bending options, such as using `typeRep :: Typeable a => proxy a -> TypeRep`. Then we can use `ScopedTypeVariables` to bring the appropriate type into scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Data.Typeable
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

-- don't forget the forall, it's a STV requirement
retrieveEntity :: forall a. (FromJSON a, Typeable a) => Text -> IO a
retrieveEntity id = do
    let jsonFileName = getPath (typeRep ([] :: [a])) id ".json"
    result <- parseFromJsonFile jsonFileName
    return result

getPath :: TypeRep -> Text -> String -> String
getPath tr id ex = "data/" ++ show tr ++ "." ++ unpack id ++ ex

parseFromJsonFile :: FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO a
parseFromJsonFile fileName = do
    contentBytes <- B.readFile fileName
    case eitherDecode contentBytes of
        Left msg -> fail msg
        Right x  -> return x
```

Comment: I don't think putting the recursive solution first is a good idea. The key point is that `typeOf` and `typeRep` don't even care about their arguments. I think this answer should mention, in order, the most modern way, being `typeRep (Proxy @a)` (or `[]`), the slightly less modern one, which is `typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)`, and the only-use-in-case-of-compatibility one, which is the recursive definition. An explanation for *why*, in any case, is the most important thing. Also, this seems to be OP's first exposure to `Typeable`. Explaining how it works would be good.

Comment: Both solutions work nicely. The RecursiveDo definitely was some mindbending food for thought! I've created a complete example implementaion based on the ScopedTypeVariables approach here: https://github.com/thma/EntityRestService